# Content of popover is not showing (or is white)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have managed to make a popover but unfortunately, the content is that is blank. It could be white too , I am not sure.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." > Popover on bottom </button>
```

here is my javascript code...

```
<script>  
$(function () { $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(); });

</script>
```

I got twitter bootstrap imported too. The code is pretty direct and I can't figure out why the data-content isn't working. The popup size does change if I increase/decrease the content.

I have used the greyscale template in bootstrap.( If that helps)

Comment: Seems to work for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/h3YNj/

Comment: My content is appearing in white...how do I change that to black? because by default, the text in my page is white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that any other CSS is affecting you popover content making it of white color.
Try adding the below CSS code to your HTML page:

```
<style type="text/css">
.popover-content{
    color: #000000 !important;/*black color*/
}
</style>
```

Try inspecting the popover `div` element using `firebug` for the `CSS` applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a css for `.popover-content`. Like if you want the text color to be black, write `.popover-content{color: #000;}`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was from the input-append class. It sets the font size to zero.

```
font-size: 0;
```